# Continuar "do while" do último ponto

Tags: c, do-while

Existe um programa de cadastros que devo realizar, coloco as opções de cadastro e etc. Todo o código é salvo nos vetores e ficam conforme o esperado, mas quando retorno ao `main()`, ele volta ao numero 1, pois precisei inicializar o mesmo nas primeiras linhas do case.

Quero saber algum caminhos onde posso continuar a partir do ultimo ponto, por exemplo, encerrei 10 cadastros, retorno ao menu para realizar outras ações, mas quando voltar a opção de cadastro de clientes, quero que ele continue a partir do ultimo (11 e etc). Bloco do Case 1.

```
int main(void) {

//Variaveis

int opcao;
clientes cadastro[100];
int i;
char sair_cad;



//Codigo

printf("\n\n1 - Cadastrar Novo Cliente\n");
printf("2 - Cliente\n");
printf("3 - Alterar Cliente\n");
printf("4 - Excluir Cliente\n");
printf("5 - Cadastrar Automovel\n");
printf("6 - Automovel\n");
printf("7 - Alterar Automovel\n");
printf("8 - Excluir Automovel\n");
printf("9 - Locacao\n");
printf("\n  Selecione uma opcao por favor: ");
scanf("%d", &opcao);
getchar();

switch (opcao)
{
case 1: // Codigo do Cadastro de Clientes

    i = 1;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cadastro[i].codigo_cliente = i;
        printf("\n\nCodigo do cliente:  %d", i);

        printf("\nNome:  ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &cadastro[i].nome);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        printf("RG:  ");
        scanf("%s", &cadastro[i].rg);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        printf("CPF:  ");
        scanf("%s", &cadastro[i].cpf);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        printf("Endereco:  ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &cadastro[i].endereco);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        printf("Data de Nascimento:  ");
        scanf("%s", &cadastro[i].data_nasc);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        printf("Registro Habilitacao:  ");
        scanf("%s", &cadastro[i].registo_habilitacao);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        getchar();
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tCadastro Salvo com Sucesso!");
        printf("\n\n Deseja realizar outro cadastro: S/N ?:   ");
        scanf("%c", &sair_cad);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

        i = i + 1;


    } while (sair_cad != 'n');
    system("cls");

    return main();
```

Comment: `return main()`? É recursivo infinito seu código?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

A primeira coisa que precisa mudar é eliminar a chama recursiva que vai acabar trazendo problemas. Pode não causar nada no exercício, mas vai aprender errado. Isto estourará a pilha em uma execução prolongada. Resolva isto com um laço. Aí é só manter a inicialização do contador fora do laço que manterá o número que estava.

Na verdade muita coisa neste código não é uma boa, mas não vou tentar mexer nisto.

```
int main(void) {
    int opcao;
    clientes cadastro[100];
    int i = 1;
    do {
        printf("\n\n1 - Cadastrar Novo Cliente\n");
        printf("2 - Cliente\n");
        printf("3 - Alterar Cliente\n");
        printf("4 - Excluir Cliente\n");
        printf("5 - Cadastrar Automovel\n");
        printf("6 - Automovel\n");
        printf("7 - Alterar Automovel\n");
        printf("8 - Excluir Automovel\n");
        printf("9 - Locacao\n");
        printf("\n  Selecione uma opcao por favor: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        getchar();
        switch (opcao) {
        case 1: // Codigo do Cadastro de Clientes
            do  {
                char sair_cad;
                system("cls");
                cadastro[i].codigo_cliente = i;
                printf("\n\nCodigo do cliente:  %d", i);
                printf("\nNome:  ");
                scanf("%[^\n]s", &cadastro[i].nome);
                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                printf("RG:  ");
                scanf("%s", &cadastro[i].rg);
                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                printf("CPF:  ");
                scanf("%s", &cadastro[i].cpf);
                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                printf("Endereco:  ");
                scanf("%[^\n]s", &cadastro[i].endereco);
                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                printf("Data de Nascimento:  ");
                scanf("%s", &cadastro[i].data_nasc);
                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                printf("Registro Habilitacao:  ");
                scanf("%s", &cadastro[i].registo_habilitacao);
                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                getchar();
                system("cls");
                printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tCadastro Salvo com Sucesso!");
                printf("\n\n Deseja realizar outro cadastro: S/N ?:   ");
                scanf("%c", &sair_cad);
                setbuf(stdin, NULL);
                i++;
            } while (sair_cad != 'n');
        case 2:
        } while (opcao != 0);
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/AddCustomer.c).

Answer (score 0):

A solução apresentada por Maniero é válida.

Seu inimigo aqui é a chamada `return main();`, pode parecer interessante a ideia de economizar linhas de código reutilizando a função, mas no seu caso ela acaba sendo ruim, afinal estais tentando resolver todo o problema somente em uma função (a principal).

O que acontece com seu programa:

1. Inicia em Main
2. Declara variáveis.
3. Inicializa I em 1 (vetores iniciam em zero, não se preocupe, é um erro bem comum no início).
4. Faz o cadastro até usuário querer voltar ao menu.
5. Retorna main()
6. Declara Variáveis (já que não há uma referência, elas voltam a iniciar em estado zero)
   ....